# Are hardware interrupts used while controlling an LCD screen using the LiquidCrystal library?

Tags: lcd, interrupt, audio

I'm working on a tone generator project that uses [Mozzi](https://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi) to make sound (sine waves mainly). As I understand, Mozzi can glitch if used along with hardware interrupts.

The plan is to use the classic 2x16 LCD screen, but I don't know the guts of the library or interface. Are hardware interrupts used while interfacing with an LCD screen, or by the LiquidCrystal library?

Answer (score 1):

The [LiquidCrystal code](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/LiquidCrystal/blob/master/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp) shows that delays are used. That can cause audio glitches in the sound.
The LiquidCrystal library does not use interrupts.

You could try to change the LiquidCrystal code according to the instruction on the Mozzi page.